# How can you detect that your model is not the correct one?(Linear regression)

Tags: regression, linear-model, linear

So I have this question where i have solved the (a) part, but I can't figure out the (b) part, so I was hoping someone could help me in the right direction.

Assume that data comes from a model y=β0+β1x1+β2x2, where the errors ε are
independent with distribution N(0,σ2). Assume that we use least squares to fit a model
y=β0+β1x1 to the data.
(a) Derive an expression for E[ˆβ1].
(b) What analysis or tests could we perform to detect that our model is not the correct
one? Motivate your answers!

Comment: I believe the only generally valid way is to calculate the correlation of the residuals with the $X_2$ variable which you did not include in your model. Other procedures, such as examining the distribution of residuals, may help in some cases, but I don't think they always guarantee finding evidence that the model was not chosen correctly.

Comment: "Added variable plot" is a good search term.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to seeing the assumptions, I am referring to checking the normality of the residuals, homoscedasticity, linearity, autocorrelation and multicollinearity.  you can perform a t-test for the coefficients.  the t-test has beta = 0 as the null hypothesis, so a small p-value is evidence that the parameter and the feature should not be discarded. You can also perform F test to perform a model selection and verify that the features should be included. I hope it helps you.